# Graphics FillRectangle except Specified Area (.NET, GDI+)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, gdi+, clipping

I would like to use **Graphics.FillRectangle** or **Graphics.Clear** with semi-transparent colour (e.g. ARGB=128,0,0,0) to darken entire area of the **Graphics** object except some specified (rectangular) area:

[image]

I know this can be achieved with four **FillRectangle** calls, but I wonder if it cannot be done easier.

I am aware of simple clipping (**Graphics.SetClip**), but this allows me to clip everything outside the specified area and I would like to achieve the opposite.

Comment: Posting some code, my help us answer.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the library, so this may be too naive, but: could you do it in two `FillRectangle` calls? One that darkens the whole image, and another that just effectively removes the darkening from the specified area?

Comment: @Paul: Yes this is possible, but have few drawback: You need access to bitmap pixels (this is not possible when you have Graphics object only), darkening followed by lightening is less efficient than clipping and it is a lossy adjustment (ale pixels which are too dark get clipped to 100% black and never get recovered).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Dim img = Bitmap.FromFile("C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg")

Using gfx = Graphics.FromImage(img)
    Dim r = New Rectangle(100, 150, 50, 50)
    gfx.SetClip(r, Drawing2D.CombineMode.Exclude)
    Using b = New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, 0, 0, 0))
        gfx.FillRectangle(b, New Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height))
    End Using
    Me.PictureBox1.Image = img
End Using
```